# map string sequence with a condition

Tags: python, string, dictionary, lambda

I am trying to use map to avoid loop in Python in order to get better performance. my code is

```
 def fun(s):
      result = []
      for i in range(len(s)-1):
          if (s[i:i+2]=="ab"):
              result.append(s[:i]+"cd"+s[i+2:])
      return result
```

My guess for the function is:

```
def fun(s):
      return map(lambda s : s[:i]+"cd"+s[i+2:] if s[i:i+2]=="ab", s)
```

However, I do not know how to associate i with s in this case... And the function above is wrong in syntax.
Anyone could help?

-------------------------------------------------------Add explanation-------------------------------------------------------
 A lot of people are confused why I do this. The idea simply comes from [Python performance document](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips)(see Loop section) and [Guido's article](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/). I am just learning.

Big thanks to @gboffi, perfect and neat answer!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you HAVE to use `map` and `lambda`? what you are doing with a loop  can be done (easily) with a list comprehension...

Comment: given we all ignore what you are trying to achieve: `[s[:p]+"cd"+s[p+2:] for p,_ in enumerate(s) if s[p:p+2]=="ab"]` with `s='123ab67'` gives `['123cd67']`. Which is an awful way to replace `ab` with `cd`

Comment: As I said, I am trying to use map to avoid loop to enhance the performance. According to Guido's performance and Python document, replacing a loop by map can enhance the performance much faster. I try to learn this trick

Comment: Let us assume there are a lot of 'ab' can be replaced by 'cd' here. The condition I just made up to solve the question. It isn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A Possible Solution

I've written the function using two auxiliary definitions, but if you want you can write it as a one liner,

```
def fun(s):
    substitute = lambda i: s[:i]+'cd'+s[i+2:]
    match = lambda i: s[i:i+2]=='ab'
    return map(substitute, filter(match, range(len(s)-1)))
```

it works by creating a list of indices for which `s[i:i+2]` matches `'ab'` using `filter` and mapping the string substitution function only for the indices that matched.

## Timings

It is apparent that there is a large overhead due to the compilation of the lambdas at each invocation but furtunately it is easy to test this hypotesis

```
In [41]:  def fun(s):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        if (s[i:i+2]=="ab"):
            result.append(s[:i]+"cd"+s[i+2:])
    return result
   ....: 

In [42]: def fun2(s):
    substitute = lambda i: s[:i]+'cd'+s[i+2:]
    match = lambda i: s[i:i+2]=='ab'
    return map(substitute, filter(match, range(len(s)-1)))
   ....: 

In [43]: %timeit fun('aaaaaaabaaaabaaabaaab')
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.38 µs per loop

In [44]: %timeit fun2('aaaaaaabaaaabaaabaaab')
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.74 µs per loop

In [45]: %timeit fun('aaaaaaabaaaabaaabaaab'*1000)
10 loops, best of 3: 33.7 ms per loop

In [46]: %timeit fun2('aaaaaaabaaaabaaabaaab'*1000)
10 loops, best of 3: 33.8 ms per loop

In [47]:
```

for a short string the `map` version is 50% slower, while for a very long string the timings are asymptotically equal...

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly I want!

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think that map has a performance advantage over a for loop.
If 's' is large then you may use xrange instead of range https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange

Second map can not filter elements, it can only map them to a new value.
You may use a comprehension instead of a for loop, but i don't think you get a performance advantage either.

Comment: interesting read, especially the linked document https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/